# Camera doesn't open from webview in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to show the camera in WebView.The webview has a feature that allows the user to scan documents. I got it to work using WebChromeClient. But I am unable to do that. I have seen other references but they could not help me. Is there anything that I have missed on the below code?

**I have added permissions to the AndroidManifest.xml file:**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <user-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

In my fragment webview.kt is:

```
class WebView : Fragment() {
                private lateinit var binding: FragmentWebviewBinding
        
            override fun onCreateView(
                inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                savedInstanceState: Bundle?
            ): View {
                binding =
                    FragmentWebviewBinding.inflate(
                        inflater,
                        container,
                        false
                    )
        
                return binding.root
            }
        
            override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
                setUpWebView()
            }
        
            private fun setUpWebView() {
                listener?.showLoading(true)
        
                binding.securityWebView.apply {
                    webViewClient = customWebViewClient
                    webChromeClient = customWebChromeClient
                    loadUrl(
                    "https://onlinecamscanner.com/")
                    settings.apply {
                        javaScriptEnabled = true
                        allowFileAccess = true
                        allowContentAccess = true
                        javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
                        domStorageEnabled = true
                        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false
                        setSupportZoom(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        
            private val customWebViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                    listener?.showLoading(true)
                }
        
                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                    listener?.showLoading(false)
                }
        
                override fun onReceivedError(
                    view: WebView?,
                    request: WebResourceRequest?,
                    error: WebResourceError?
                ) {
                    super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
                    listener?.showLoading(false)
                }
            }
        
            private val customWebChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
        
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                override fun onPermissionRequest(request: PermissionRequest?) {
                    super.onPermissionRequest(request)
                }
        
                override fun onPermissionRequestCanceled(request: PermissionRequest?) {
                    super.onPermissionRequestCanceled(request)
                    request?.deny()
                }
            }
        }
```

- Compile SDK version = 31
- Target SDK version = 31
- Min Version = 21

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try it, to add permissions in webview

```
private void setMyWebviewSettings(WebSettings MyWebviewSettings) {
    MyWebviewSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    MyWebviewSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    MyWebviewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    MyWebviewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    MyWebviewSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    MyWebviewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    MyWebviewSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    MyWebviewSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    MyWebviewSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
}
```